# Problem insert data to sql using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert data in Mysql into a table name wp_stuff. Wordpress didn't show me any error but the data is not being inserted. Where is the error of following code?

```
<form method="post"> //I also used here action attribute.
    Stuff Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    ....... so on....
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data">

    </form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     global $wpdb;

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];

        ...... so on.....



         $user_details = array('name' => $name, 'f_name' => $f_name, 'm_name' => $m_name, 'b_date' => $b_date, 'gender' => $gender, 'b_group' => $b_group, 'photo' => $photo, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'present_address' => $present_address, 'permanent_address' => $permanent_address, 'nid' => $nid, 'exp' => $exp, 'at' => $at, 'other_file' => $other_file, 'al' => $al, 'u_name' => $u_name, 'password' => $password, 'd_name'=> $d_name, 'in_time' => $in_time, 'out_time' => $out_time, 'j_date' => $j_date, 'salary' => $salary);

        $table_name =$wpdb->prefix."stuff";
        $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $user_details, array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%b','%s','%s','%s','%s','%b','%b','%b','%b','%b','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%i'));


    };

    ?>
```

Comment: Just print the insert query and try to execute mysql quey editor. and just show the error occurred in that.

Comment: Please check error logs, you can use var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. `array('%s')` format is optional.

```
<form method="post"> //I also used here action attribute.
    Stuff Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    ....... so on....
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data">

</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    global $wpdb;

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];

    ...... so on.....


     $user_details = array('name' => $name, 'f_name' => $f_name, 'm_name' => $m_name, 'b_date' => $b_date, 'gender' => $gender, 'b_group' => $b_group, 'photo' => $photo, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'present_address' => $present_address, 'permanent_address' => $permanent_address, 'nid' => $nid, 'exp' => $exp, 'at' => $at, 'other_file' => $other_file, 'al' => $al, 'u_name' => $u_name, 'password' => $password, 'd_name'=> $d_name, 'in_time' => $in_time, 'out_time' => $out_time, 'j_date' => $j_date, 'salary' => $salary);

    $table_name =$wpdb->prefix."stuff";
    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $user_details);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove format from

```
$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $user_details, array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%b','%s','%s','%s','%s','%b','%b','%b','%b','%b','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%i'));
```

use this instead

```
$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $user_details);
```

and check once if data insert done succesfully or not.

if data successfully inserts then problem is in your format array.

as in format %d for integer, %f for float and %s for string and you are using %b & %i which is wrong because of this your data is not inserting.

you can check it from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/).

Comment: what are the values for blob? such as %s for string. then what is for blob?

Comment: %d or %s both will work to store data in blob datatype